# Summing the value part from object of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "Year":1990 , 
    "Africa":0.0 , 
    "Asia":13500 , 
    "Europe":1947, 
    "Latin America\/Carribean":3000
  },
  {
    "Year":1991, 
    "Africa":234, 
    "Asia":16500, 
    "Europe":197, 
    "Latin America\/Carribean":3000
  }
]
```

I want to add all the values by year like adding the values of Africa Asia Europe and latin america/carribean.

Example : For year 1990 I want to sum 0, 13500, 1947, and 3000 and for 1991 I want to sum 234, 16500, 197, and 3000.

I have 48 rows I have to add them and get an array without using loops how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var array = [{
  "Year": 1990,
  "Africa": 0.0,
  "Asia": 13500,
  "Europe": 1947,
  "Latin America\/Carribean": 3000
}, {
  "Year": 1991,
  "Africa": 234,
  "Asia": 16500,
  "Europe": 197,
  "Latin America\/Carribean": 3000
}];

var result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(c);
  let value = keys.reduce((_, k) => {
    if (k !== 'Year') {
      return _ + c[k];
    }
    
    return _;
  }, 0);
  
  a[c.Year] = value;
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)